# Find objects in model by relative condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I`m new to RoR. Please help me:
I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
end
```

and

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :foreign_key => "game_id"
end
```

Game objects have many users. I need to find all Game objects, where users.count == 1. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit long but this worked for me:

```
 Game.joins(:users).where("(select count(users.game_id) from users users2 where users2.game_id = games.id) = 1")
```

You can use `includes()` or `joins()` depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

MrYoshiji's answer is close, but instead of trying to use `where`, you need to use `group` and `having`.

For example:

```
Game.joins(:users).group("users.game_id").having("count(users.game_id) = 1")
```

That will produce the following query:

```
SELECT games.* FROM "games" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."game_id" = "games"."id" GROUP BY users.game_id HAVING count(users.game_id) = 1
```